# CDMI based storage cloud. Interoperability?

Tags: cloud, storage

I am doing a project on CDMI based Storage Cloud.

Can anyone explain, what does "interoperability" exactly mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Interoperability is nothing but ability to work with each other. Cloud storage has multiple types of cloud data storage interfaces that are able to support both legacy and new applications.To work with these interfaces, existing standard protocols such as iSCSI (and others) for block and CIFS/NFS or WebDAV for file network storage etc. are used.

Answer (score 1):

Today, the protocols that exist to access data from an object store are all specific to the object store implementation for example S3, OpenStack Swift have their own additions to HTTP that are used to access data in them. Clients talking to any one of these clouds cannot talk to the other directly. The clouds themselves dont talk to each other.

SNIA came up with CDMI for interoperability so that if many object stores implement the CDMI protocol, clients written for one cloud can be (largely) re-used to talk to all clouds that implement CDMI protocol for access. Moreover, clouds can talk to each other and federate. So, CDMI is a client to cloud and cloud to cloud interop protocol.